# Oracle to SQL Server convertion (+) operator

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm converting an oracle sql command to sql server
Does anyone know the alternative to the command (+) of oracle?

Oracle

```sql
select X.A, X.B FROM T1 X, T2 Y WHERE X.A = Y.A(+) AND X.B = Y.B(+)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle and SQL Server select (+) equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994381/oracle-and-sql-server-select-equivalent)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does (+) mean in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549798/what-does-mean-in-sql)

Comment: Honestly, it's 2021; *long* past time you stopped writing SQL like it's the 1980's. The Explicit JOIN syntax has been around for **29 years** now.